# Velocity.js versus CSS transition transform fps performance

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, velocity.js

I have always been under the impression that CSS `transform` has the best animation performance over any other options hands down. After all, the animations are handled by the GPU in a separate thread. So I have spent hours if not days building an (almost hacky) [approach to mimic jQuery slideUp/slideDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496535/how-to-animate-height-with-transform-without-squishing-content).

But recently I have been reading about the [glories of Velocity.js](https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation). It is often stated that Velocity has better performance than CSS. But few people mention CSS `transition: transform`.

I definitely see the advantages in JS powered animations because of the higher level of control. So this brings me to the question: How does Velocity stack up to `transform` in terms of fps performance in general?

I am asking this as a general question, but [here](https://codepen.io/cytek04/pen/rNZOyoM) is a CodePen of my actual use case if you are wondering. This question matters to me because in my real world scenario smoothness is VERY important.